# TopicClient not sending + no exceptions thrown

Tags: c#, azureservicebus, azure-sdk-.net

We are using a TopicClient to push messages to subscribers, in order to test some possible cases, we disabled the topic (to simulate to the best of our knowledge an heavy server load).

Now, when we enable the topic (using the Microsoft Service Bus Explorer), the `TopicClient` doesn't send the messages to the subscribers. This isn't what worries me, as the topic should never be disabled in prod. But why doesn't throw an exception?

This is the part of the code that sends messages :

```
NamespaceManager namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(ConnectionString);

if (!namespaceManager.TopicExists(TopicName))
    namespaceManager.CreateTopic(TopicName);

_client = TopicClient.CreateFromConnectionString(ConnectionString, TopicName);

try
{
    _client.Send(message);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    //Doesn't get in here when the topic is re-enabled, usually does (when needed).
}
```

Comment: I wonder is the subscribers were suspended from when the topic was disabled (and subsequently not reactivated). Try creating a new subscriber and then sending a message to the topic.

Comment: I'll try this today and get back to you about it